# Get filename within project in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I need to get extract a filename from within my project with Ruby and extract the first word from it. I have tried it with a solution I found here on this site, but without success:

```
File.basename("/path/to/folder/here_is_my_file.rb").match(/[^_]+/)
```

this returns => "here" as expected.

What I need, however, is to fetch "here" without knowing what it is supposed to be, since the first part of the filename is dynamically generated. Therefore I need to find a way to extract it dynamically.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: If you know `/path/to/folder`, then you can get all the files in the directory using the `Dir` class. Take a look at the Ruby API: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html#method-i-each Perhaps there is a better way to solve this problem. What is dynamically generating these files and what is your use case?

Comment: The filename is the condition for starting different "jobs" within the project. So depending on what a file is named and where it is found in the system a different method will be called.

Comment: If the file has a name like "main_file.rb" than it should call a certain method, if the file is named like "sub_file.rb" another action should be called.

Comment: What I don't understand is how these files are getting there are how Rails knows to look for them. If some daemon is putting files in the system, why not just hit the Rails stack instead with all of the required job information?

Comment: The files are generated by other people working on the same project with the action that should be called on them as the first part of the filename. This particular line is for a Helper to figure out how to proceed with files at a given directory.

Comment: I don't really understand. You would have a higher probability of getting an answer if you clearly outline what you are trying to do, and added an example of the entire workflow.

Comment: `File.basename("/path/to/folder/main_file.rb").match(/[^_]+/)` returns "main". `File.basename("/path/to/folder/sub_file.rb").match(/[^_]+/)` returns "sub". This sounds like what you want-- if it's not what you want, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes it does, BUT the thing is that the first part ("main", "sub" in the example) could be anything. So what I need is to extract that part, but I can't use File.basename without the exact path. So if there was a way to define the path with a variable this wouldn't be a problem any more.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to take a crack at this, too. What information _do_ you have about the file/path in question? For instance, if the variable `pathname` contains the pathname to the file, then `File.basename(pathname).match(...)` would seem to return what you want.

Comment: I know the exact folder where the file is located and the file extension of the file in question. So in other words: I know everything besides the * from the following "/path/to/folder/*_my_file.rb".

Comment: `Dir['/path/to/folder/*_my_file.rb']` will give you all files that match that pattern, then you can iterate over the collected files and extract that `*` and do your conditions check. If that's what you want.

Comment: yes, that is what I am after.

Comment: @kiddorails, you should post an answer, which can then be accepted so this question won't be counted as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to find the files on your path which match the pattern `*_file.rb`.
To do that, use the *globbing* from [`Dir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Dir.html) class in Ruby.

```
matched_files = Dir['/path/to/folder/*_file.rb']
#=> ['/path/to/folder/main_file.rb', '/path/to/folder/sub_file.rb', '/path/to/folder/foo_file.rb']
```

Now, you can extract the basename by iterating over those files:

```
base_files = matched_files.map { |file| File.basename(file) }
#=> ['main_file.rb', 'sub_file.rb', 'foo_file.rb']
```

Additionally, if you just want to extract **main**, **sub**, **foo** from that, you can match against the pattern to do that as:

```
base_files.map { |file| file.match(/(.*)_file.rb/)[1] }
#=> ['main', 'sub', 'foo']
```

With the files name collected, you can check those names against your conditionals to execute whatever is meant for that file..

Good luck.